# Dyntable sort does not work at all from Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dynatable

I am using dyna table with Ajax. Sorting, searching, pagination nothing is working. I only get a list in my table but on clicking the column header nothing happens.

Please help.This is my code.

My html file is

```
<table style="width:100%" id="my-final-table" class="tablesorter" >
    <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="#239B56">
          <th><font style="color:#fff">Rollno</font></th>
          <th><font style="color:#fff">Name</font></th>
          <th><font style="color:#fff">Marks</font></th>
          <th><font style="color:#fff">Percentage</font></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

My Ajax code is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.dynatable.js"></script>
<style src="/jquery.dynatable.css"></style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#my-final-table').dynatable({

          dataset: {
            ajax: true,
            ajaxOnLoad: true,
            ajaxUrl: '/result_analysis_subject_json.json',
            records: []
        }
    });


    });

</script>
```

And my JSON file is

```
{"records":[{"rollno":"1","name":"Aditya Kumar Sharma","marks":"12.00","percentage":40},{"rollno":"2","name":"Aksh Kathuria","marks":"19.00","percentage":63},{"rollno":"3","name":"Anant ","marks":"14.00","percentage":47},{"rollno":"4","name":"Arnav Arora","marks":"28.00","percentage":93},{"rollno":"5","name":"Ayush Sai Raina","marks":"26.00","percentage":87},{"rollno":"6","name":"Ayush Rawat","marks":"21.00","percentage":70},{"rollno":"7","name":"Bhagya Dua","marks":"11.00","percentage":37},{"rollno":"8","name":"Bhvesh Gautam","marks":"26.00","percentage":87},{"rollno":"9","name":"Chaitanya Dubey","marks":"18.00","percentage":60},{"rollno":"10","name":"Chanchal","marks":"5.00","percentage":17},{"rollno":"11","name":"Deeksha","marks":"28.00","percentage":93},{"rollno":"12","name":"Dimple Bhatia","marks":"26.00","percentage":87},{"rollno":"13","name":"Ekta Yadav","marks":"27.00","percentage":90},{"rollno":"14","name":"Eshan Sharma","marks":"24.00","percentage":80},{"rollno":"15","name":"Harman Arora","marks":"13.00","percentage":43},{"rollno":"16","name":"Himanya ","marks":"18.00","percentage":60},{"rollno":"17","name":"Hiya Bhatia","marks":"29.00","percentage":97},{"rollno":"18","name":"Ishmeet Kaur","marks":"13.00","percentage":43},{"rollno":"19","name":"Jivitesh Gwadi","marks":"20.00","percentage":67},{"rollno":"20","name":"Jiya Hussain","marks":"7.00","percentage":23},{"rollno":"21","name":"Krish Kohli","marks":"13.00","percentage":43},{"rollno":"22","name":"Krishna Sharma","marks":"22.00","percentage":73},{"rollno":"23","name":"Lisha Kapoor","marks":"27.00","percentage":90},{"rollno":"24","name":"Mannant Sehgal","marks":"20.00","percentage":67},{"rollno":"25","name":"Mayank Mehta","marks":"19.00","percentage":63},{"rollno":"26","name":"Mehak Singh","marks":"26.00","percentage":87},{"rollno":"27","name":"Nandini Bhargava","marks":"29.00","percentage":97},{"rollno":"28","name":"Parth Talwar","marks":"27.00","percentage":90},{"rollno":"29","name":"Pawni Yadav","marks":"27.00","percentage":90},{"rollno":"30","name":"Prachi Dahiya","marks":"21.00","percentage":70},{"rollno":"31","name":"Prachi Sharma","marks":"18.00","percentage":60},{"rollno":"32","name":"Rashi Bainsla","marks":"19.00","percentage":63},{"rollno":"33","name":"Ravinder Singh","marks":"5.00","percentage":17},{"rollno":"34","name":"Riya Sethi","marks":"14.00","percentage":47},{"rollno":"35","name":"Sahib Kharbanda","marks":"24.00","percentage":80},{"rollno":"36","name":"Sajal Kukreja","marks":"23.00","percentage":77},{"rollno":"37","name":"Shrishty Singh","marks":"26.00","percentage":87},{"rollno":"38","name":"Tanisha Kaur","marks":"26.00","percentage":87},{"rollno":"39","name":"Toshiv Mudgal","marks":"16.00","percentage":53},{"rollno":"40","name":"Yash Anand","marks":"23.00","percentage":77}],"queryRecordCount":40,"totalRecordCount":40}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what i can read from the documentation , the sorting, searching, and paginating needs to be done on the server side

> NOTE: When using AJAX to load data, operations such as sorting, searching, and paginating are performed on the server before building the returned JSON. This example has these features disabled since, we're just loading a static JSON file for the purposes of documentation.
>
> When using Dynatable in "AJAX mode" (`dataset.ajax = true`), delegates all operations (pagination, sorting, and querying/filtering) to the server. For each operation, dynatalbe culls the parameters (sort, search, page) into an AJAX request and fetches the results from `dataset.ajaxUrl` (if this setting isn't set, it will send an AJAX request to the URL of the current page).

[more info](https://www.dynatable.com/?sorts%5Byear%5D=1#json-from-ajax)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What if I use Dynatable on a html table. Will it do the sorting then on the page or does it still needs to be done on the server side ?

Comment: from what i can tell from the library **only for the ajax mode** is required sorting/searching/pagination on the server side

Answer (score 0):

in the ajax call

records: function myFunction(rec){}

perform your js library code in myFunction on rec